# Перевод строки в математическое выражение

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как мне перевести строку (например,"5*2") в пример и вывести его решение?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = 1
>>> eval('x+1')
2
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Good luck:)

Comment: `eval('__import__("shutil").rmtree("/")')`